# Delete records from a table whose combination of fields do not exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable1
(
    ID INT,
    txtName VARCHAR(100), 
    txtValue VARCHAR(100),  
)

CREATE TABLE MyTable2
(
    ID INT,
    txtName VARCHAR(100), 
    txtValue VARCHAR(100),  
)
```

I want to delete all records from `MyTable2` whose `txtName` and `txtValue` fields are not assigned to a record in `MyTable1`. Please let me know how to achieve this using SQL.

Comment: Did you try anything on your own? If so, you should have posted it with your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `not exists()`:

```
delete t2
from MyTable2 t2
where not exists (
  select 1
  from MyTable1 t1
  where t1.txtName = t2.txtName
    and t1.txtValue = t2.txtValue
    )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GBJK11263